# How to make list of numbers from string using range()?

Tags: string, list, vim, split, range

I know that you can create a list of numbers from a string using the split function:

```
let Items = '1,3,5,7'
let MyList = split(Items, ',')
echo MyList --> [1,3,5,7]
```

but how can I make a list of numbers from a string using `range()`?

this doesn't work (trailing characters error):

```
let Items = '1,100,2'
let MyList = range(eval(Items))
echo MyList --> trailing characters error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval(Items)` does not make any sense. You probably want something along this:

```
:let Items='1,100,2'
:let MyList=split(Items,',')
echo range(MyList[0],MyList[1],MyList[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

To use eval you must have a string representing ("containing") a complete expression. If you want to use your `Items` string as arguments to the `range` function, then you can concatenate a string representing the `range` invocation and evaluate it like so:

```
let Items = '1,100,2'
let MyList = eval( 'range(' . Items . ')' )
```

I don't think it's a great idea to do it this way, but it's possible.

`eval` does the reverse of `string` for lists and dicts, so an alternative to using `split(Items)` to get a list would be `eval('[' . Items . ']')`. But splitting the string seems easier and is also safer.